# Struts 2 error - com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, annotations, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm trying to run Struts2 sample application.While starting the server I'm getting below error and code which using from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_annotations.htm). I implemented same code same jars over here.

> struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.1.2.jar,     asm.jar,
>   antlr-2.7.6.jar,     commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar,
>   commons-io-2.0.1.jar,     commons-lang-2.5.jar,
>   commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,     commons-logging-api-1.1.jar,
>   freemarker-2.3.18.jar     javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar,     ognl-3.0.4.jar,
>   struts2-core-2.3.1.2.jar,     xwork-core.2.3.1.2.jar

```
Jun 29, 2013 6:58:18 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Unable to read class [com.tutorialspoint.struts2.Employee]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2854)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:780)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.<init>(ClassFinder.java:165)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.findActions(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:376)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:334)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.commons.EmptyVisitor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 36 more
Jun 29, 2013 6:58:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jun 29, 2013 6:58:18 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
```

Comment: Are you deploying all the required libraries?

Comment: Yes , all jar which required.

Comment: I'm skeptical, because you're missing a dependency, or are moving library versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add/replace the following jar files

```
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
```